# Div at the bottom of a bootstrap 4 carousel

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I'm trying to put a div with 4 fontawesome icons at the bottom of a bootstrap 4 carousel,but in this moment,the div it's right near the menu button.I want to look like this: [image: This]
I have the carousel all set up, but i don't know how to place the div down there.

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="home-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/slider1.jpg');?>" alt="First slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h2 class="animated bounceInRight to-deelay">Comanda Mancarea Ta Favorita</h2>
            <button class="btn btn-primary menu-button animated bounceInLeft to-deelay">Meniu</button>
            <div class="test-div">
                test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/slider2.jpg');?>" alt="Second slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h2 class="animated bounceInRight to-deelay">Comanda Mancarea Ta Favorita</h2>
            <button class="btn btn-primary menu-button animated bounceInLeft to-deelay">Meniu</button>
            <div class="test-div">
                test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/slider3.jpg');?>" alt="Third slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h2 class="animated bounceInRight to-deelay">Comanda Mancarea Ta Favorita</h2>
            <button class="btn btn-primary menu-button animated bounceInLeft to-deelay">Meniu</button>
            <div class="test-div">
                test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#home-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#home-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
    .carousel-caption{
    padding-bottom: 150px;
}
.carousel-caption h2{
    font-size: 50;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.carousel-caption{
    color: black;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.to-deelay{
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.menu-button{
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #C0B283;
    border: 0;
}
.carousel-caption button{
    text-align:center;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #C0B283 50%,#DCD0C0 50%);
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    transition:all 1s ease;
}
.carousel-caption button:hover{
    background-position: right bottom;
}

.test-div{
    width: 70%;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Beside that,what is the best way to space the elements from the carousel caption?

Comment: Look in to [Bootstrap 4's flex utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#align-items), specifically _align-items_ which allows for vertical spacing and alignment. They're really useful for stuff like this.

Comment: where you want to place the div with that icons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try an answer to get you started.

So you want to place the div which contains you icons and text just above you `carousel-control-prev` element.

so the HTML should look something like:

```
    <div class="icon-container">
        <div class="icon-1"> CONTENT </div>
        <div class="icon-2"> CONTENT </div>
        <div class="icon-3"> CONTENT </div>
        <div class="icon-4"> CONTENT </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#home-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#home-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

The idea being that you can now absolute position the `icon-container` div to the bottom of the carousel. The pagination elements of the carousel will be styled similarly but just to the left and right side of the carousel respectively.

so your CSS for the container should look something like

```
.icon-container{
   position:absolute;
   width:100%;
   bottom:30px;
   left:0;
   right:0;
}
```

This should position this div at the bottom of the carousel. assuming the parent has a `position:relative;` attribute.

Comment: Thank you!
I needed centered, so i used right:0;
    left:0;,but the answear it's good!

Comment: Oh yes! of course it's 'right:0; left:0;' My apologies, late in the day...

Comment: This'll work fine. Personally though, it seems a shame not to use what bootstrap has built in (flex).

Comment: That is a good idea! When I get a chance I'll update my answer and include it as an alternate.